# How can I easily pre-determine what sort of armor a follower will prefer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Spun off from this answer:  [My housecarls won't stay dressed!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47071/my-housecarls-wont-stay-dressed/47133#47133)

Apparently, certain characters will just outright refuse to keep on any clothes that don't meet their particular preference.  For some it might be Heavy Armor, for some it might be Light Armor, and I'm sure others prefer robes or plain clothes.

Is there a way (maybe a list I haven't found yet?) to determine who would like to wear what, before giving them any items?

Also, all the housecarls I've had so far seem to come standard with Steel Armor.  Does this mean they all prefer Heavy Armor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The followers page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) at the UESP wiki lists what skills each follower has. You can see that all Housecarls are [one handed warriors](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:CombatWarrior1H#CombatWarrior1H) who specialise in heavy armor.

Comment: I see the "one-handed warriors" bit, but could you point me to the specifics about the armor type?  I may just be missing something.

Comment: If you click the warrior link it takes you to the second page I linked which has a table with their skills.

Comment: For reference, housecarls are "CombatWarrior1H". For other types of follower it lists on the first page I linked their skills, e.g. "J'zargo, A male Khajiit Sorcerer trained in destruction, illusion, one-handed, and heavy armor". If their skills are not listed in the description you need to click the "class" link to see what their skills are.

Answer (score 1):

If your smithing is high, you should be able to upgrade light and heavy armor bracers with roughly equivalent armor rating (Leather and Iron).  These bracers will overwhelm the follower's default bracers.  The follower would then choose the better bracers based on their skill modifier.  See which bracers the follower likes.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I've given Iona a complete set of fully-enhanced Dragonscale aromor, and she won't keep it on because it's Light Armor.

Comment: @Iszi, I'm suggesting a way to determine which armor is preferred. I'm not suggesting that you give the wrong armor to the follower (as you suggest). Please review.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding.  However, I still do not consider this as answering the question.  The question is how to determine their preference *before* giving them anything.  Trial and error is therefore not an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Iszi, no the question is "before giving them a choice item?" Upgraded leather and iron bracers are not "choice" items. They are actually inexpensive.

Comment: I'm sorry.  It seems I mis-conveyed my intentions in the question.  Edited for clarity.