# How to make my follower to wear same type of armor as her default, but improved?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Long story short: my loyal follower Lydia is now a Blade. Upon taking her oath, she got full set of Blades armor and it became her default armor meaning it's not seen in her inventory - not even when pickpocketing her.

I also got my own full set of Blades armor and being good hearted thane decided to improve it and give to Lydia so she will have better chance surviving the oncoming battles. I improved it all to Epic and gave to her, however she just won't wear it, staying with her default and plain set.

1. The armor rating is **much** better in every piece of armor.
2. If I give her different type of armor with better rate she wear it on spot.

So,  while it's quite obvious what's causing this issue I have no idea how to "fix" it other than killing her, taking the plain set from her body then revive her with console. So far I managed without console and really hope to keep my hands clean.

I went over all answers in [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36994/my-companion-wont-wear-her-armor) and the one suggesting [using a mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8530) sounds promising, but prefer to hear someone confirming this mod before installing it.

Any ideas? Maybe there is a way to make her resign from the Blades?

Comment: There is a good answer  [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/in-skyrim-can-i-get-my-companion-to-change-robes)

Comment: I understand and share your aversion to using the console, but fixing/working around bugs is where I draw the line and use it.

Comment: @Taz thanks but both answers just repeat stuff already answered in the other question I linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod you linked to, **[TCG - Tradable Companion Gear](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8530)** can indeed allow you to remove all of your follower's equipment, even those that are considered part of your follower's "default gear" (doesn't appear in the follower's inventory, and is unremovable in the vanilla game) - the Blades armor, in this case.

TCG is now also part of a bigger follower ovehaul mod, **[UFO - Ultimate Follower Overhaul](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14037)**. They are made by the same author.

TCG description from its webpage:

> - All followers gear can be traded.
> - Default hidden bow and arrows are tradable and not respawnable.
> - Followers will not revert to default outfits or unequip gear even if dismissed.
> - Followers will wear what is placed in their inventory.

With TCG or UFO, just open up the item inventory screen of Lydia and remove her default Blades armor, and then put in the improved Blades armor that you have.

Comment: Thanks, TCG sounds just enough. You speak from experience?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, but with [UFO](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=14037) (which is a follower overhaul mod that also contains TCG's functionality in it). (TCG and UFO have the same author.) I've removed [Aranea Ienith](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aranea_Ienith)'s 'default' blue mage robes with it (she prefers it to the much better [Archmage's Robes](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archmage's_Robes)).

Comment: I installed a mod from http://steamcommunity.com in the past and saw somewhere it's better not to mix mods from http://skyrim.nexusmods.com as well - guess such thing is not worth the risk. Tried [this mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=15925&searchtext=companion) but it did not have any effect.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't see any reason why you shouldn't mix mods from Steam Workshop and Skyrim Nexus (they're both just websites where you can download mods; some mods are available at both websites). Just use [BOSS (Better Oblivion Sorting Software)](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=6) to automatically set the optimal load order of the mods, before running the game. [Nexus Mod Manager (NMM)](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/content/modmanager/) can handle the mods downloaded from Steam Workshop and Skyrim Nexus just fine, AFAIK.

Comment: @ShadowWizard NMM can only *uninstall* mods installed through NMM, though, AFAIK. I'm also interested in knowing where you've read that it's better not to mix mods from Nexus and the Steam Workshop.

Comment: Can't find it now so guess you're right. Any simple way to install nexus mods like I can just "Subscribe" to steam workshop mods? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You can use [Nexus Mod Manager (NMM)](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/content/modmanager/) along with the ['Download with Manager' link on a Nexus mod page](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=14037) to have NMM download and then install the mod. You can also use the manual 'Download' link with NMM - just open up the downloaded mod file with NMM.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried to do a minor edit, but the site won't allow editing of comments older than 5 minutes, so I just deleted and resubmitted it again. Sorry about that.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Will give it a go soon and update. (time for cleanup :))

Comment: Thanks, it worked - sort of. After installing the mod and loading, Lydia appeared with her default Steel Armor which appeared in her inventory. I took it away just to have her put the Blades armor that still did not appear in the inventory - however, after giving her the Epic Blades armor she put on herself the last given piece. Couldn't make her wear all the set but better than nothing, I guess..

Comment: @ShadowWizard I reported that as a bug at the [UFO thread](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/633542-ufo-ultimate-follower-overhaul/page__view__findpost__p__5151386) and at the [TCG thread](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/558126-tcg-tradable-companion-gear/page__view__findpost__p__5151391).

Comment: @ShadowWizard The author of UFO has replied to the [bug report here (link)](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/633542-ufo-ultimate-follower-overhaul/page__view__findpost__p__5151901): "*What you do in that case is just tell the follower "You could dress better" and his blades armor will be spawned in their inventory*".

Comment: Thanks, actually installed TCG not UFO and there's no such menu option. It already cause some trouble - Lydia now occasionally reverts back to Steel armor and I have to take it away from her when it happens. No biggie but I fear mods do have their downsides.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Did you ask your current follower to leave before installing TCG? If not, try doing that in an older savegame where TCG hasn't been installed yet, and see if the "You could dress better" conversation option appears. I'll follow this up at the UFO or TCG thread when I get time later.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [From TCG's author](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/633542-ufo-ultimate-follower-overhaul/page__view__findpost__p__5159134): "*Check that you are using the correct freeformskyheaventempleascript.pex. Sounds like you have one from a different mod. Extracting TCG script back into scripts folder should solve your issue.*"

Comment: I tried to mess around with the load order of the mods, never manually copied any files. I do have the other mod (from Steam Workshop) as well so maybe this cause conflicts?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It could be so. Check out the links I posted above of the reply of the TCG author. He mentioned that it may be a mod conflict too. You could also just post there so they could help you troubleshoot mod conflicts. Always use [BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=6) to sort your load order. Also, check out if any mods you have modify anything related to the Blades or Sky Haven temple.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you - I decided to ditch this whole thing, not worth all those efforts. I will give Lydia my own Ebony set when I upgrade to Dragon Armor set soon so she will both look good in it and have good protection. Thanks for all the help, and I do hope it will also help others with this same issue. :)

Comment: Hi, are the mods still applicable to Skyrim SE? Or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: @LoreFriendly I'm not sure. I don't have Skyrim SE and I haven't played Skyrim in years.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are playing on the PC, the following steps should work:

- Open the console
- Click on her face
- Type `removeallitems` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can not see her armor because she has it equipped. This prevents you from stealing it via pick pocketing unless you have the perk that allows you to do just that, take what is equipped.

When having the same suit of armor but you have improved it either through smithing or enchanting the gear, the only way that the NPC will equip it is if it was their gear to begin with. This means you have to steal what they are wearing, boost its abilities in any way you see if and then return it to them before the magical tick time that will respawn their gear.

If you do a bit of browsing on some fan sites (I recommend the Unofficial Elder Scrolls Project's Wiki) you can even find a list of NPCs and how many pieces of 'natural' gear they have that you can then take and improve for them. Maybe someone will be kind enough to edit that URL in here for the both of us.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Take all the stuff that's in her inventory . Then give her your swanky blades armor .
If you are worried about Lydia dying then don't. Only you can kill your follower . They will withstand infinite amount of hurt from enemies but not from you

> Maybe there is a way to make her resign from the Blades ?

Yes. Go to the temple and talk to Lydia . When the dialog menu pops up select the follow me option .

Comment: Nope - she died several times all by herself when fighting big bosses or horde of enemies. Selecting "follow me" is not making her quit or resign anything - she's still a Blade just following me.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because clearly you have no idea what your talking about.